# EntityFramework gives IDisposable error

Tags: entity-framework

I use EF for the back-end DataLayer in my asp.net websites. I create a class library and add the Model in it, reference it and use it from the ASP.NET Website. But this time, I generated the model from database but it seems does not implement IDisposable, and the methods I used to see are not there. DeleteObject , SaveChanges etc. There are only Two tables in the DB and the Model was generated with only the TableSets and two methods AddToTableSet ... Had anybody encountered such a problem?
[alt text http://techlipse.net/EF-problem.jpg](http://techlipse.net/EF-problem.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

Did you extend the generated ObjectContext and then perhaps rename it in the EDMX?  You might be looking at your part of the partial class here without the generated part.

What does the Properties panel say for your EDMX for "Entity Container Name"?

When you right click on Entities and go to definition do you get to the correct generated class?

**And lastly, but probably most likely, did you perhaps delete the Reference to `System.Data.Entity` from the project or not reference it in your web project?**

Is you web project even a Web Application project???

Comment: Thanks, I had this exact same problem, and your solution in bold fixed it for me!

Answer (score 4):

I have my Entity Framework code in its own project, and was referencing it from a separate project. NuGet sets EntityFramework only on the EF project, which is how the reference gets automatically configured to the latest version. To fix this error:
**Tools** -> **Library Package Manager** -> **Manage Nuget Packages for Solution**
Select **Installed Packages** and find **Entity Framework**
Click the Manage Button, and check all the project that will be accessing the EF Data Model.

Comment: This answer fixed the problem for me, there some other sources on internet telling to add reference to EF separately, but this method is so neat ! +1 :-)